# Photo is never shown in Gallery in a new folder

Tags: android, android-camera, android-bitmap

I am trying to take a picture or select it from gallery, compress it and save it in a separate folder on my phone. The photo is taken and put into the `imageview` but I can't find it in `gallery`, even after couple of minutes. What might be the problem?

`String mPhotoLocation;`

```
private void takePhoto() {
    Intent takePhoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = photoPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
            getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
            photoFile);
    takePhoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
    startActivityForResult(takePhoto, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}
```

**Compressing the image**

```
public String compressImage(String imageUri) {

    String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
    int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

    float maxHeight = 816.0f;
    float maxWidth = 612.0f;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
        } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

        }
    }

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

    try {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileOutputStream out;
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String photoName = "PHOTO_" + timestamp + "_";
    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File myDirectory = new File(root, "/Test");
    if (!myDirectory.exists()) {
        myDirectory.mkdirs();
    }
    File f = new File(myDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), photoName);
    String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
    mPhotoLocation = filename;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return filename;
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
    Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
    Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }
    final float totalPixels = width * height;
    final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
    while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize++;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: did u add permissions in manifest for read and write external storage ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082326/android-custom-camera-photos-not-shown-in-gallery?rq=1

Comment: @quicklearner Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Call this method After saving image

```
  public static void notifySystemGallery(Context context, File file) {
    if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "notifySystemGallery: the file do not exist.");
        return;
    }

    try {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(),
                file.getName(), null);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
}
```

Comment: I call your method on this file `File f = new File(myDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), photoName);` but the pictures are put in a folder called `Pictures` instead of `Test`

Comment: try this code in above method`MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });`

Comment: I've been using that code and it sometimes worked, sometimes did not. With the code provided as answer, it works but they are put in a different folder than the one I specify.

Comment: Check out your file url this work perfectly in my app

Comment: I tried debugging everything seems fine, but the images are put in `Pictures` folder...